# "truffle init" not working after installing

Tags: truffle, nodejs, npm

After I install truffle with:

> $ npm install -g truffle

And get:

> /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.5.0/bin/truffle -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
>
> truffle@5.0.26 postinstall /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js
>
> -Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
>
> +truffle@5.0.26
>
> updated 1 package in 4.593s

I then can't run "truffle init", this is the error I get:

> -bash: truffle: command not found

I am running Node v.12.5.0 and Npm v.6.9.0

What do I need to do to be able to run "truffle init"? I have been searching to no avail.

Comment: Your truffle executable is under `/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.5.0/lib/node_modules/.bin/`. Maybe add this path to the list of execution-paths of your operating-system .

Comment: I'll try this out. How do I go about doing so?